# How to get the user android version ,name when the application is installed?

Tags: android

when user installed my application I want to get the users android OS(version, Name) to validate .I tried with different examples but cant find the solutions and wasted my time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
      android.os.Build.VERSION
```

It provides info about:

1. **CODENAME:** The current development codename, or the string "REL" if this is a release build.
2. **INCREMENTAL:** The internal value used by the underlying source control to represent this build.
3. **RELEASE:** The user-visible version string.
4. **SDK_INT:** The user-visible SDK version of the framework; its possible values are defined in Build.VERSION_CODES.

For more info: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Comment: @Deepak if my answer helped you kindly accept it by clicking on the TICK mark